# Running terraform init and plan commands on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to run the two commands shown below on AWS lambda using python 3.7:

```
run_command("terraform init -reconfigure -upgrade")
run_command("terraform plan -out=plan.tfstate")
```

Below is the run_command function:

```
def run_command(command):
    command_list = command.split(' ')

    try:
        logger.info("Running shell command: \"{}\"".format(command))
        result = subprocess.run(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
        logger.info("Command output:\n---\n{}\n---".format(result.stdout.decode('UTF-8')))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Exception: {}".format(e))
        return False

    return True
```

I installed the terraform zip as an AWS layer but when I try to run the terraform init/plan commands shown above I get the errors below.

```
[INFO]  2021-08-11T22:58:59.435Z    515d3670-be7c-46e1-8098-920ec9c63891    Running shell command: "terraform init -reconfigure -upgrade"
[ERROR] 2021-08-11T22:58:59.475Z    515d3670-be7c-46e1-8098-920ec9c63891    Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'terraform': 'terraform'
[INFO]  2021-08-11T22:58:59.476Z    515d3670-be7c-46e1-8098-920ec9c63891    Running shell command: "terraform plan -out=plan.tfstate"
[ERROR] 2021-08-11T22:58:59.496Z    515d3670-be7c-46e1-8098-920ec9c63891    Exception: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'terraform': 'terraform'
```

I know that I am in the correct directory with a main.tf file when running the terraform command so that isn't the issue. Thus, why am I getting these errors?

I am not sure why I am getting these errors because I used the same process to run AWS CLI commands on lambda, and it is working correctly.

Comment: Sounds like `terraform` is not properly installed and in the `PATH`

Comment: I would not recommend running `terraform` in Lambda. One big caveat with Lambdas is that they only run 900 seconds (15 minutes). There are things that take way longer to deploy than 15 minutes. For example: Elasticsearch instances in AWS, updates to large DynamoDB tables etc. And then your terraform times out possibly leaving you with a broken Terraform state and broken infrastructure. Please, don't do that.

Comment: @Jens if they are just running `plan`, which is what is stated in the question, then they should be fine. I agree that running `apply` in a Lambda environment is not going to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you create the layer? If on a linux machine, please be sure, to set chmod 755 before zipping the terraform binaries. If on windows, see alternative:

If this is not working, here is an **alternative**:

Run a chmod 755 within your Lambda to the binary before run the terraform cli.

Be sure, you downloaded the Linux version of terraform. I did the same with terraform cli and also with mysqldump binary, so this procedure should work (but not within a layer, maybe you have to pack it into your main source.

**Side note:**
Use Python 3.8 for your lambda

Comment: The layer I used is simply the terraform_0.10.8_linux_amd64.zip file from this website, https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.10.8/, which has the binaries in a zip file.